# How do I find this $\begin{vmatrix} A&B\\ B&A \end{vmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B$ be matrices such that $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}, B=(b_{ij})_{n\times n}$, $$b_{ii}=2a_{ii},$$ and
$$b_{ij}=\begin{cases}
a_{ij}&i>j\\
-a_{ij}&i<j
\end{cases}$$ for $(i,j=1, 2, 3, \cdots , n)$.

Find $$\begin{vmatrix}
A&B\\
B&A
\end{vmatrix}.$$

My try: 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
A&B\\
B&A
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}&a_{11}&-a_{12}&-a_{13}&\cdots&-a_{1n}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n}&a_{21}&a_{22}&-a_{23}&\cdots&-a_{2n}\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots&a_{nn}&a_{n1}&a_{n2}&a_{n3}&\cdots&a_{nn}
\end{vmatrix}$$ 
then I can't carry on. Maybe there's some other nice method.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the formula $\left|\begin{array}{ccc}A & B\\ B & A\end{array}\right| = det(A-B)det(A+B)$ from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices)

Comment: This formula how can prove? can you post this formula proof?Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof of Albert's formula:

$$\left|\begin{smallmatrix} A&B\\B&A\end{smallmatrix}\right|=\left|\begin{smallmatrix} A-B&B-A\\B&A\end{smallmatrix}\right|=\left|\begin{smallmatrix} A-B&0\\B&A+B\end{smallmatrix}\right|=|A-B||A+B|$$

Step 1: Subtract 2nd row of blocks from 1st row.

Step 2: Add 1st column of blocks to 2nd column.

Step 3: Matrix is block triangular.

Comment: Thank you,can post your reslut? Thank you

Comment: @chinamath, I don't understand what you're asking for.  This is the proof you asked for.